# meSpeak.js - second word does not play when using a CallBack Method

Tags: javascript, text-to-speech, intervals

I've written some simple javascript using the MeSpeak library from http://www.masswerk.at/mespeak/

What I'm trying to do is pause between words for a few seconds if the input script contains brackets and a number (i.e. - "[3]" would pause for 3 seconds)...

I've already seen a more elegant method elsewhere, however, what is stumping me here is why does the following code not play the second word? (tested in FireFox version 25.0.1 with version 1.8.1 of meSpeak)

Code follows:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="mespeak.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button onclick="speakdata('Testing Word [2]Another [3]Again [5]Blah')">Talk</button>
    <div id="audio"></div>
                <script>
                meSpeak.loadConfig("mespeak_config.json");
                meSpeak.loadVoice("voices/en/en-us.json");
                var t=0;
                var speechArr = [];
                var pauseArr = [];
                var len =0;
                var recurseLoop = 0;
                function speakdata(spokendata) {
                    var looper = new Boolean();
                    looper = true;
                    var posCount = new Number(0);
                    var pauseCount = new Number(0);                 
                    while (looper)
                    {
                        if (spokendata.substring(posCount).indexOf("[") == -1) {
                            speechArr.push(meSpeak.speak (spokendata.substring(posCount)),{ 'rawdata': true });
                            pauseArr.push(0);
                            len++;
                            looper = false;
                        } else {
                            if (posCount == 0) {
                                speechArr.push(meSpeak.speak(spokendata.substring(posCount,spokendata.indexOf("[")-1),{ 'rawdata': true }));
                                pauseArr.push(0);
                                len++;
                            }
                            pauseCount += parseInt(spokendata.substring(posCount).substring(spokendata.substring(posCount).indexOf("[")+1, spokendata.substring(posCount).indexOf("]")))
                            posCount = parseInt(posCount+spokendata.substring(posCount).indexOf("]")+1)
                                if (spokendata.substring(posCount).indexOf("[") != -1) {
                                    var posCount2 = spokendata.substring(posCount).indexOf("[");
                                    speechArr.push(meSpeak.speak(spokendata.substring(posCount,posCount2+posCount),{ 'rawdata': true }));
                                    pauseArr.push(pauseCount*1000);
                                    len++;
                                    posCount = posCount2+posCount
                                    looper = true;
                                } else {
                                    speechArr.push(meSpeak.speak(spokendata.substring(posCount),{ 'rawdata': true }));
                                    pauseArr.push(pauseCount*1000);
                                    len++;
                                    looper = false;
                                    }
                                }
                    }
                    setTimeout(function(){meSpeak.play(speechArr[0],1,playNext)},pauseArr[0]);
                    recurseLoop++;                  
                }

                function playNext() {
                    if (recurseLoop < len) {
                        setTimeout(function(){meSpeak.play(speechArr[recurseLoop],1,playNext)},pauseArr[recurseLoop]);
                        recurseLoop++;
                    }
                }
                </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It plays it but not always. And it complains with: `meSpeak: Can't play, not an Array, or ArrayBuffer, or base64-String. `

Comment: It seems like 2 seconds delay for 2nd word is not enough. I changed it to [3] and now it works. Even with 3s word `Another` is spoken immediately after `Testing Word`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So .... I think I found it:

```
setTimeout(function(){meSpeak.play(speechArr[0],1,playNext)},pauseArr[0]);
recurseLoop++; 

function playNext() {
  if (recurseLoop < len) {
    setTimeout(function(){meSpeak.play(speechArr[recurseLoop],1,playNext)},pauseArr[recurseLoop]);
    recurseLoop++;
  }
}
```

logs for me the sequence:

```
timeout to 0 Testing Word
playing "Testing Word"
timeout to 1 Another 
playing "Again "
timeout to 2 Again 
playing "Blah"
timeout to 3 Blah
playing undefined
Speak: Can't play, not an Array, or ArrayBuffer, or base64-String: [object Undefined]
ended
```

Please mind the "recurseLoop++;" just after the timeout!

This effects to

- setTimeout to play speechArr[0], increment recurseLoop (now 1)
- call to playNext() after speechArr[0], recurseLoop === 1
- call setTimeout
- increment recurseLoop (recurseLoop === 2)
- timeout comes back plays speechArr[2]
- call to playNext(), recurseLoop === 2
- call setTimeout
- increment recurseLoop (recurseLoop === 3)
- timeout comes back plays speechArr[3]

Changing your code to increment just at the very beginning of "playNext()" solves the issue:

```
setTimeout(function(){meSpeak.play(speechArr[0],1,playNext)},pauseArr[0]);

function playNext() {
  if (++recurseLoop < len) {
    setTimeout(function(){meSpeak.play(speechArr[recurseLoop],1,playNext)},pauseArr[recurseLoop]);
  }
}
```

This logs to the following sequence:

```
timeout to 0 Testing Word
playing "Testing Word"
timeout to 1 Another 
playing "Another "
timeout to 2 Again 
playing "Again "
timeout to 3 Blah
playing "Blah"
ended
```

(I was so mesmerized by the *undefined* value that looked like a bug in mespeak.js or in addressing meSpeak.speak() that I totally missed this skipping in the iteration at first – see the other try on this.)

Answer (score 0):

There is an error in the parenthesis in the first if-clause:

```
if (spokendata.substring(posCount).indexOf("[") == -1) {
  speechArr.push(meSpeak.speak (spokendata.substring(posCount)),{ 'rawdata': true });
  /* ... */
} else {
  /* ... */
}
```

so it is

```
  meSpeak( spokendata.substring(posCount) ), { 'rawdata': true }
```

where "{ 'rawdata': true }" is *not* included as an option-object to speak().
(In fact the object forms a separate statement separated by the comma.)

So speak() returns "undefined", since it is not called to return any sound-data.
As a consequence of this *undefined* is then used as an argument to play() (which fails, since there is no sound data for playback).

What you want would be:

```
  speechArr.push(meSpeak.speak (spokendata.substring(posCount), { 'rawdata': true }));
```

Other: Just updated meSpeak to v.1.8.3, which now logs any erroneous type forwarded to play(). Also there's now a small timing gap before cleaning up any sound-data to work around a timing issue with Chrome (sometimes Chrome is still playing when the reported duration of the sound is reached). Additionally, we 1) now clean-up the internal filesystem and 2) return a unique, newly produced array in case speak() is called to return an array. http://www.masswerk.at/mespeak

On methods producing any special gaps directly in meSpeak:

a) Most unlikely option first: You could try mark-up/HTML-input using the "ssml"-option. (Maybe any tags would produce a   gap of any length).

b) Probably the easiest option: You could use line-breaks ("\n") providing any length for the extra-gap with the "linebreaks" option (e.g. 'meSpeak.speak("this is a\n pause", { "linebreaks": 3})')

c) Finally you could provide any phonemes producing a pause directly in the input string (as phoneme tags). The eSpeak documentation gives the following example for an input string including phonems: "[[D,Is Iz sVm f@n'EtIk t'Ekst 'InpUt]]" (See the very end of the page http://espeak.sourceforge.net/commands.html)

On phonemes generally: "Phoneme mnemonics can be used directly in the text input to espeak. They are enclosed within double square brackets. Spaces are used to separate words, and all stressed syllables must be marked explicitly. eg:
[[D,Is Iz sVm f@n'EtIk t'Ekst 'InpUt]]" (http://espeak.sourceforge.net/phonemes.html)

The eSpeak documentation links to the following resource as a documentation of the phoneme-mnemonics: http://www.kirshenbaum.net/IPA/ascii-ipa.pdf

Comment: The first if statement is only evaluated if there is no bracketed input into the method - Whilst this could cause an issue if the input was a single string of words, the input example clearly shows the [x] seperator - As I stated in the initial question, it works correctly except for the second string/word input into the method, can you explain why "Another" doesn't play? Even if I correct the parenthesis in the initial "if" statement, the second segment (after the "]") does not play.

Comment: Not really. Please try version 1.8.3! (The previous code was analogous to speak.js, which used the array produced by the filesystem. In case this array would be returned to represent a stream to be cached, it might be overridden by the next call to speak(). This is now changed (we now use a newly generated array for any call). P.S.: I really would love to recompile eSpeak with emscripten (since meSpeak is based on quite dated code), but the last few SDKs fail to produce a working JS-code (resulting in "wav.wav" to be undefined). Did anyone succeed with this recently?

Comment: But please mind that each time play() failed, speak() returned 'undefined' (checked both in your code and logged in mespeak.js). I was able to catch this in the first if-clause. Also, I would recommend using some like 'meSpeak.speak("this is a\n pause", { "linebreaks": 3})' to have the gaps produced by meSpeak.

Comment: Sorry, last statement isn't true (not caught inside the if-clause). I'll have another look at this.

Comment: Found it – put it in a separate answer. (It's in the iteration of recurseLoop.)